# Why is it recommended against using a dynamic start_date in Airflow?

Tags: airflow

I've read Airflow's FAQ about ["What's the deal with `start_date`?"](https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/faq.html#what-s-the-deal-with-start-date), but it still isn't clear to me why it is recommended against using dynamic `start_date`.

To my understanding, a DAG's `execution_date` is determined by the minimum `start_date` between all of the DAG's tasks, and subsequent DAG Runs are ran at the latest `execution_date` + `schedule_interval`.

If I set my DAG's `default_args` `start_date` to be for, say, yesterday at `20:00:00`, with a `schedule_interval` of 1 day, how would that break or confuse the scheduler, if at all? If I understand correctly, the scheduler would trigger the DAG with an `execution_date` of yesterday at `20:00:00`, and the next DAG Run would be scheduled for today at `20:00:00`.

Is there some concept that I'm missing?

Answer (score 17):

First run would be at `start_date+schedule_interval`. It doesn't run dag on `start_date`, it always runs on `start_date+schedule_interval`.

As they mentioned in document if you give `start_date` dynamic for e.g.  `datetime.now()` and give some `schedule_interval`(1 hour), it will never execute that run as `now()` moves along with time and `datetime.now()+ 1 hour` is not possible

Comment: so how often does the scheduler calculate `start_date`? does it calculate it before every run?

Comment: I think I'm getting confused by this: if `start_date` is `datetime.now()` at time `t`, then `t` should have been saved somewhere, right? so when `t + 1` finally comes around, the scheduler should know to start the run, given that it doesn't calculate `start_date` again

Comment: @earthican This is not clearly mentioned in the documentation. Other thing I would like to mention if you are making any changes in start_date or schedule_interval, always modify the name of dag like my_dag_v1 or something. Your changes with start_date or interval will not work if you don't change the name of dag

Comment: I accept that using `datetime.now()` is a bad idea but what is the alternative when I'm writing a DAG that will be deployed at an undetermined time in the future? I have a scenario where I don't want to set `start_time: datetime.datetime(2019,4,29)` with a schedule of every 1 hour because if I deploy it in 3 weeks time its going to run 21*24=504 times, and I don't want that to happen.

Comment: @liferacer You say *Your changes with start_date or interval will not work if you don't change the name of dag*. Do you mean one needs to change the name of the .py file, or the value assigned to `dag_id`?

Comment: @jamiet one option is to set catchup=False when creating the DAG, but this prevents catchup going forward too which may not be what you want. The only way around that I've seen is to set the start_date appropriately. Disclaimer: just getting started with Airflow.

Comment: Setting catchup=False will only take care of previous backfills but still very often create atleast one instance when you unpause the dag after some time of pausing. This behavious is good for ETL processes but for crons not as intuitive. As an example if I have something scheduled at 10 every day and i pause it for a few days. If today I unpause it at 8, it is going to immediately trigger a run for the previous 1 day atleast even when catchup=False.

Answer (score 1):

The scheduler expects to see a constant start date and interval.  If you change it the scheduler might not notice until it reloads the DagBag, and if the new start date doesn't line up with your old schedule it might break depends_on_past behavior.

If you don't need depends_on_past the simplest might be to stop using the scheduler, set the start date to some arbitrary old date, and externally trigger the DAG however you like using a crontab or similar.