# Airflow scheduler is not picking up job

Tags: cron, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I've created a new Dag with following arguments:

```
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime.now(),
    'email': ['airflow@example.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
    'catchup': False,
    # 'queue': 'bash_queue',
    # 'pool': 'backfill',
    # 'priority_weight': 10,
    # 'end_date': datetime(2016, 1, 1),
    # 'wait_for_downstream': False,
    # 'dag': dag,
    # 'adhoc':False,
    # 'sla': timedelta(hours=2),
    # 'execution_timeout': timedelta(seconds=300),
    # 'on_failure_callback': some_function,
    # 'on_success_callback': some_other_function,
    # 'on_retry_callback': another_function,
    # 'trigger_rule': u'all_success'
}

dag = DAG(
    'sample_dag',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='sample dag',
    schedule_interval="44 * * * *")
```

But the scheduler is not picking up the dag when the time comes. And it is running fine when I manually trigger it. Is there anything I'm missing here?

Also, the scheduler was throwing an error when the cron expression was `"*/5 * * * *"`

```
CroniterBadCronError: Exactly 5 or 6 columns has to be specified for iteratorexpression.
```

But the cron expression looks good me.

Comment: What is the result of `airflow list_dags`

Comment: `sample_dag` is part of the output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this is that the `[time the dag runs]` = `start_date` + `schedule_interval`. So if you set your `start_date` to something that is dynamic then the dag will never execute since the `start_date` keeps increasing with time.

It is explained [here](https://airflow.apache.org/faq.html#what-s-the-deal-with-start-date) and there is also another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41134524/why-is-it-recommended-against-using-a-dynamic-start-date-in-airflow) on stack which has an answer too, they probably explain it better than I do.

You should change your `start_date` to something static rather than `datetime.now()`

If you do not want backfilling in your dag you need to set the `catchup=False` as a dag parameter. so something like the following:

```
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2018, 1, 1),
    'email': ['airflow@example.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5)
}

dag = DAG(
    'sample_dag',
    catchup=False,
    default_args=default_args,
    description='sample dag',
    schedule_interval="44 * * * *"
    )
```

Comment: Lets say a dag needs to run every 5 mins and don't need to backfill it... then what should I specify the `start_date` as?

Comment: Just set it to some arbitrary time in the past and make sure that you have `catchup=false` as a parameter to your dag (not as the `default_args` as you've done). Example here -> https://airflow.apache.org/scheduler.html#backfill-and-catchup