# Can't able to run a Task in Airflow

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

Whenever I tried to run my DAG it gets success state but it can't able to run the task.
While running the first time it works perfectly

**trigger_controller_dag.py:**

```
def conditionally_trigger(context, dag_run_obj):
    c_p = context['params']['condition_param']
    if context['params']['condition_param']:
        dag_run_obj.payload = {'message': context['params']['message']}
        pp.pprint(dag_run_obj.payload)
        return dag_run_obj

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='example_trigger_controller_dag',
    default_args={
        "owner": "airflow",
        "start_date": datetime.utcnow(),
    },
    schedule_interval='@once',
)

trigger = TriggerDagRunOperator(
    task_id='test_trigger_dagrun',
    trigger_dag_id="example_trigger_target_dag",
    python_callable=conditionally_trigger,
    params={'condition_param': True, 'message': 'Hello World'},
    dag=dag,
)
```

**trigger_target_dag.py:**

```
args = {
    'start_date': datetime.utcnow(),
    'owner': 'airflow',
}

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='example_trigger_target_dag',
    default_args=args,
    schedule_interval=None,
)


def run_this_func(ds, **kwargs):
    print("Remotely received value of {} for key=message".
          format(kwargs['dag_run'].conf['message']))


run_this = PythonOperator(
    task_id='run_this',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=run_this_func,
    dag=dag,
)
```

While running the DAG I am getting the following error,
**dependency 'Task Instance State' FAILED: Task is in the 'success' state which is not a valid state for execution. The task must be cleared in order to be run**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `start_date` variables in both DAGS are dynamic and may be causing your problem `'start_date': datetime.utcnow()`. Setting them to a dynamic start is not recommended and leads to errors.

Try setting it to a static start date like `'start_date': datetime(2019, 5, 29) #year month day`

Taken from [Airflow FAQ](https://airflow.apache.org/faq.html)

> We recommend against using dynamic values as start_date, especially
>   datetime.now() as it can be quite confusing. The task is triggered
>   once the period closes, and in theory an @hourly DAG would never get
>   to an hour after now as now() moves along.

Another SO question on this: [why dynamic start causes issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41134524/why-is-it-recommended-against-using-a-dynamic-start-date-in-airflow)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `schedule_interval='@once'` try `schedule_interval=None`.

`@once` means it will only run one time.