# How to run an Airflow DAG once after x minutes?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I need to run a DAG exactly once, but waiting 10 minutes before:

```
with models.DAG(
        'bq_executor',
        schedule_interval = '@once',
        start_date= datetime().now() + timedelta(minutes=10) ,
        catchup = False,
        default_args=default_dag_args) as dag:
       // DAG operator here
```

but I can't see the execution after 10 minutes. Something wrong with `start_date`?

If I use `schedule_interval = '*/10 * * * *'` and `start_date= datetime(2019, 8, 1)` (old date from now), I can see the excution every 10 minutes

Comment: It is [strongly recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41194998/3679900) that you DON'T use `datetime.now()` in `start_date`

Answer (score 2):

Dont use `datetime.now()` as it will keep on changing whenever the DAG is loaded and now() + 10 minutes will always be a future timestamp resulting in DAG never getting scheduled.

Answer (score 1):

Airflow runs the DAGS you have added always AFTER the start_date. So if you have start_date today, it will start after today 23:59.

Scheduling is tricky for this, so check the documentation and examples:
https://airflow.apache.org/scheduler.html

In you case, just switch the start_date to yesterday (or today -1) and it will start today with yesterday's ds (date stamp)