# Conditional Tasks using PythonOperator and BranchPythonOperator

Tags: airflow

Hi Guys am new to airflow and python. I need to run the tasks based on the value of a variable in the input json. If the value of the variable '**insurance**' is "**true**" then task1, task2, task3 need to run else task4, task5, task6 need to run. Since am a newbie to this i dont have much idea about the usage of PythonOperator & BranchPythonOperator.

This is my input json:

```
{
  "car": {
    "engine_no": "123_st_456",
    "json": "{\"make\":\"Honda\",\"model\": Jazz, \"insurance\":\"true\",\"pollution\":\"true\" }"
  }
}
```

The code is given below:

```
from airflow import DAG
from datetime import datetime
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.operators import PythonOperator
import logging
import json

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False
}

dag = DAG('DAG_NAME',default_args=default_args,schedule_interval=None,max_active_runs=5, start_date=datetime(2020, 8, 4))   

PythonOperator(
   task_id = 'sample_task',
   python_callable = 'sample_fun',
   op_kwargs = {
       json  : '{{ dag_run.car.json}}'
   },
   provide_context=True,
   dag = dag
)

def sample_fun( json,**kwargs):
  insurance_flag = json.dumps(json)['insurance']

task1 = BashOperator(
    task_id='task1',
    bash_command='echo 1'
)

task2 = BashOperator(
    task_id='task2',
    bash_command='echo 2'
)

task3 = BashOperator(
    task_id='task3',
    bash_command='echo 3'
) 

task4 = BashOperator(
    task_id='task4',
    bash_command='echo 4'
)  

task5 = BashOperator(
    task_id='task5',
    bash_command='echo 5'
)

task6 = BashOperator(
    task_id='task6',
    bash_command='echo 6'
) 


if insurance_flag == "true":
    task1.dag = dag
    task2.dag = dag
    task3.dag = dag
    task1 >> task2 >> task3
    
else:
    task4.dag = dag
    task5.dag = dag
    task6.dag = dag
    task4 >> task5 >> task6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Primary problem in your code

1. The *dag-definition-file* is [continuously parsed by Airflow in background](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58105738/3679900) and the generated DAGs & tasks are picked by scheduler. The way your file wires tasks together creates several problems

   - **all 6 tasks** (`task1` .. `task6`) are ALWAYS created (and hence they **will always run, irrespective of `insurance_flag`**); just their *inter-task dependency* is set in accordance with `insurance_flag`
   - the correct way instead is to put both *task instantiation* (creation of `PythonOperator` `taskn` object) as well as *task wiring* within that `if .. else` block. That ways, the unnecessary tasks won't be created (and hence won't run)
2. While the point 1. above alone should be enough to fix your code, may i offer you a suggestion for improvement: having a `Variable` being read in *dag definition file* means a **SQL query being fired by Airflow's `SQLAlchemy` `ORM` very frequently in background** (every cycle of continuously parsing dag-definition file)

   - this not just unnecessarily overloads your SQLAlchemy backend meta-db, but also slows down parser (in extreme case can lead of [DagBag timeout](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/configurations-ref.html#dagbag-import-timeout) if parsing starts taking too long)
   - instead you can leverage that [`BranchPythonOperator` in right way](https://www.astronomer.io/guides/airflow-branch-operator/) to move that Variable reading on *runtime* (when DAG / tasks will be actually run) rather than *Dag generation time* (when dag-file is parsed by Airflow and DAG is generated on webserver); here is the code for that (and you should do away with that if-else block completely)

   ```
   """ branch 1 """
   task1 >> task2 >> task3
   """ branch 2 """
   task4 >> task5 >> task6

   def branch_decider(**kwargs):
       my_var_dict = Variable.get('my_var_name', deserialize_json=True)
       # decide which branch to take based on insurance flag
       if my_var_dict['car']['json']['insurance']:
           return 'task1'
       else:
           return 'task4'

   branch_task = BranchPythonOperator(task_id='branch_task',
                                      dag=dag,
                                      python_callable=branch_decider)
   ```

---

### Other (minor) problems in your code

- Missing mandatory `dag` argument from `task` instantiations

  ```
     task1 = BashOperator(
       task_id='task1',
       bash_command='echo 1',
       dag=dag
     )
  ```
- a *dagling* `PythonOperator` with a `callable` which *`json.dump`s* Variable that is solving no purpose (unless i misunderstood you code / intent here, remove it completely)

  ```
  PythonOperator(
      task_id='sample_task',
      python_callable=sample_fun,
      op_kwargs={
          json: '{{ dag_run.car.json}}'
      },
      provide_context=True,
      dag=dag
  )


  def sample_fun(json, **kwargs):
      insurance_flag = json.dumps(json)['insurance']
  ```

---

**UPDATE-1**

*Responding to queries raised over comments*

> We have used Variable.get( my_ var_ name). What is this my_ var_ name

[Variables](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/concepts.html#variables) have a `key` & `value`, `my_var_name` is the `key` of variable (see the `Key` column in following screenshot from Airflow UI)

[image: Airflow Variable UI]

---

> If condition satisfies return 'task1', 'task2', 'task3' else 'task4', 'task5', 'task6'. Can we add more than 1 tasks in return

No you can't. (you don't have to)

`BranchPythonOperator` requires that it's `python_callable` should return the `task_id` of first task of the branch only

- 1st branch: `task1`, `task2`, `task3`, first task's `task_id` = `task1`
- 2nd branch: `task4`, `task5`, `task6`, first task's `task_id` = `task4`

Furthermore do understand that since the above two sets of tasks have already been *wired* together, so they will be naturally executed after one-another in that sequence (otherwise what would be the point of wiring them anyways?)

```
task1 >> task2 >> task3
```

Check out these links (in addition to links already inlined in answer above)

- (official repo) [example_branch_python_dop_operator_3.py](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/example_dags/example_branch_python_dop_operator_3.py)
- (official repo) [example_branch_operator_3.py](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/example_dags/example_branch_operator.py)
- [AirflowPythonBranchOperator examples](https://gist.github.com/BenjaminDebeerst/fc217aa178aa648db2aa04ab6fdd71ae) (note the incorrect name of Operator here)

Comment: Thanks y2k-shubham for the detailed explanation. It will be better to get clarity in some areas.We have used Variable.get( my_ var_ name). What is this my_ var_ name.     One more doubt based on conditions can we use like this . If condition satisfies return 'task1', 'task2', 'task3' else 'task4', 'task5', 'task6'. Can we add more than 1 tasks in return.

Comment: Thanks y2k-shubham for the detailed explanation. One thing i dont get is that for my case what should i give value for my_var_name. Our input json is passed through ARC(Advanced Rest Client). Are you suggesting to give the key as my_var_name and the json as value?

Comment: **@Joe1988** yes. in your question when you said `..based on the value of a variable in the input json..`, it gave me the impression that you are referring to [Airflow `Variable` concept](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/concepts.html#variables). If it is just a python string variable that is holding this string, then `Variable.get(..)` is not needed

Comment: Even though we define branch_task where should we use that?

Comment: Big effort on the response.. well done!