# How to access Xcom value in a non airflow operator python function

Tags: airflow

I have a stored XCom value that I wanted to pass to another python function which is not called using PythonOperator.

```
def sql_file_template():
    <some code which uses xcom variable>

def call_stored_proc(**kwargs):
        
        #project = kwargs['row_id']
        print("INSIDE CALL STORE PROC ------------")   
        query = """CALL `{0}.dataset_name.store_proc`(
                          '{1}' # source table
                        , ['{2}'] # row_ids
                        , '{3}' # pivot_col_name   
                        , '{4}' # pivot_col_value
                        ,  100 # max_columns
                        , 'MAX' # aggregation
                );"""
        query = query.format(kwargs['project'],kwargs['source_tbl'] ,kwargs['row_id'],kwargs['pivot_col'],kwargs['pivot_val'])
        job = client.query(query, location="US")
        for result in job.result():
            task_instance = kwargs['task_instance']
            task_instance.xcom_push(key='query_string', value=result) 
                print result
                return result



bq_cmd = PythonOperator (
    task_id=                    'task1'
    provide_context=            True,
    python_callable=            call_stored_proc,
    op_kwargs=                  {'project'        : project,
                                 'source_tbl'     : source_tbl,
                                 'row_id'         : row_id,
                                 'pivot_col'      : pivot_col,
                                 'pivot_val'      : pivot_val
                                },
    dag=                        dag
)

dummy_operator >> bq_cmd
sql_file_template()
```

The output of stored proc is a string which is captured using xcom.

Now I would like to pass this value to some python function **sql_file_template** without using PythonOperator.

As per Airflow documentation xcom can be accessed only between tasks.

Can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 3):

If you have access to the Airflow installation you'd like to query (*configuration, database access, and code*) you can use Airflow's `airflow.models.XCom:get_one` class method:

```py
from datetime import datetime

from airflow.models import XCom


execution_date = datetime(2020, 8, 28)
xcom_value = XCom.get_one(execution_date=execution_date,
                          task_id="the_task_id",
                          dag_id="the_dag_id")
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to **access XCOM outside Airflow** (probably a different project / module, **without creating any Airflow DAGs / tasks**)?

---

Airflow uses [`SQLAlchemy`](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/) for mapping all it's [`model`s](https://github.com/apache/airflow/tree/v1-10-stable/airflow/models) (including [`XCOM`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/models/xcom.py)) to corresponding SQLAlchemy backend (meta-db) tables

Therefore this can be done in two ways

1. **Leverage Airflow's SQLAlchemy model**

   (without having to create a task or DAG). Here's an *untested* code snippet for reference

> ```
> from typing import List
> from airflow.models import XCom
> from airflow.settings import Session
> from airflow.utils.db import provide_session
> from pendulum import Pendulum
>
>
> @provide_session
> def read_xcom_values(dag_id: str,
>                      task_id: str,
>                      execution_date: Pendulum,
>                      session: Optional[Session]) -> List[str]:
>     """
>     Function that reads and returns 'values' of XCOMs with given filters
>     :param dag_id: 
>     :param task_id: 
>     :param execution_date: datetime object
>     :param session: Airflow's SQLAlchemy Session (this param must not be passed, it will be automatically supplied by
>                     '@provide_session' decorator)
>     :return: 
>     """
>     # read XCOMs
>     xcoms: List[XCom] = session.query(XCom).filter(
>         XCom.dag_id == dag_id, XCom.task_id == task_id,
>         XCom.execution_date == execution_date).all()
>     # retrive 'value' fields from XCOMs
>     xcom_values: List[str] = list(map(lambda xcom: xcom.value, xcoms))
>     return xcom_values
> ```

Do note that since it is *importing airflow packages*, it still **requires working airflow installation** on python classpath (as well as connection to backend-db), but here **we are not creating any tasks or dags** (this snippet can be run in a standalone python file)

For this snippet, I have referred to [`views.py`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/www/views.py#L1103) which is my favorite place to peek into *Airflow's SQLAlchemy magic*

---

2. **Directly query Airflow's SQLAlchemy backend meta-db**

   Connect to meta db and run this query

   `SELECT value FROM xcom WHERE dag_id='' AND task_id='' AND ..`

Comment: I would like access the xcom in same code and not outside. The above code is airflow dag code and I would like access the xcom variable in same code

Comment: **@Neha0908** both the proposed solutions would work irrespective of whether you are using in Airflow code, or independent from it. When using XCOM in `task`, you get to call `xcom_pull` method from `TaskInstance` class, which is just a shortcut (underlying it uses the same thing as above). see [this](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/d7602654526fdd2876466371404784bd17cfe0d2/airflow/models/taskinstance.py#L1718) and [this](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/5c895154ed1d5df4adcdaea06ba65b8153148047/airflow/models/xcom.py#L167)

Comment: and while you can do it in a dag-definition file also, it can unnecessarily load your backend db, read [point-2 here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63255612/3679900)